# Events | jQuery or Backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Below is relevant code from Backbone.js

Are Backbone Events related to jQuery events in any way?  Or are you suppose to choose.

For example for [jQuery click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) you use:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
})
```

For backbone they [have this](http://backbonejs.org/#Events)

```
var object = {};

_.extend(object, Backbone.Events);

object.on("alert", function(msg) {
  alert("Triggered " + msg);
});

object.trigger("alert", "an event");
```

**Backbone Model w/ Event Trigger**

```
var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({
  promptColor: function() {
    var cssColor = prompt("Please enter a CSS color:");
    this.set({color: cssColor});
  }
});

window.sidebar = new Sidebar;

sidebar.on('change:color', function(model, color) {
  $('#sidebar').css({background: color});
});

sidebar.set({color: 'white'});

sidebar.promptColor();
```

**Backbone Related Event Code**

```
var Events = Backbone.Events = {
    on: function(events, callback, context) {
        var calls, event, node, tail, list;
        if (!callback) {
            return this;
            events = events.split(eventSplitter);
            calls = this._callbacks || (this._callbacks = {});
        while (event = events.shift()) {
            list = calls[event];
            node = list ? list.tail : {};
            node.next = tail = {};
            node.context = context;
            node.callback = callback;
            calls[event] = {tail: tail, next: list ? list.next : node};
        }
        return this;
    },
    off: function(events, callback, context) {
        var event, calls, node, tail, cb, ctx;
        if (!(calls = this._callbacks)) return;
        if (!(events || callback || context)) {
            delete this._callbacks;
            return this;
        }
        events = events ? events.split(eventSplitter) : _.keys(calls);
        while (event = events.shift()) {
            node = calls[event];
            delete calls[event];
            if (!node || !(callback || context)) continue;
            tail = node.tail;
            while ((node = node.next) !== tail) {
                cb = node.callback;
                ctx = node.context;
                if ((callback && cb !== callback) || (context && ctx !== context)) {
                    this.on(event, cb, ctx);
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    },
    trigger: function(events) {
        var event, node, calls, tail, args, all, rest;
        if (!(calls = this._callbacks)) return this;
        all = calls.all;
        events = events.split(eventSplitter);
        rest = slice.call(arguments, 1);
        while (event = events.shift()) {
            if (node = calls[event]) {
                tail = node.tail;
                while ((node = node.next) !== tail) {
                    node.callback.apply(node.context || this, rest);
                }
            }
            if (node = all) {
                tail = node.tail;
                args = [event].concat(rest);
                while ((node = node.next) !== tail) {
                    node.callback.apply(node.context || this, args);
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents), Backbone:

> Uses jQuery's delegate function to provide declarative callbacks for DOM events within a view.

The salient snippet of code is [this](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-156):

```
if (selector === '') {
  this.$el.bind(eventName, method);
} else {
  this.$el.delegate(selector, eventName, method);
}
```

...which asks jQuery (or zepto, or whatever else is providing the `$` operator) to handle event delegation.

So if the events in question are bound using a view's [`delegateEvents`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-156) method, the binding has happened through jQuery.

The `Backbone.Events` module itself, however, is intended for use with standalone Objects (not DOM Elements) and defined independently in the [Backbone source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-18).

Comment: and that means what? I don't see any use of jQuery in the code I posted above for Backbone.Events

Comment: "Are Backbone Events related to jQuery events in any way?"

Comment: Backbone Events are for Backbone Models....I posted relevant code I found here.....http://backbonejs.org/#introduction

Comment: Backbone Event must call something which in turn calls the DOM event

Comment: The `Backbone.Events` module may apply to just about any javascript object, and it's not uncommon to see if used outside of Backbone (e.g. as a pub/sub mediator). It's just an event queue and handlers&mdash;nothing fancy.

Comment: ok... I think backbone is only around 500 lines when you take out the comments..trying to learn the whole thing bit by bit.....so far I understand 30 lines tops....seems to do a lot of abstract things...do I need a CS course to understand this?

Comment: Probably not, but if you aren't comfortable with Javascript you'll find Backbone to be much easier to learn "by doing". The code is commented well, but (like all JS) not always incredibly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little baffling to me, I'm not sure if you wonder the ins and outs of the Backbone core vs the jQuery core, or you're stumped on MVVM and why to use it. Either way, it's irrelevant to seperate the cores of each of the libraries as they're used differently to achieve the same goals.

The two approaches are different due to frameworks. Backbone.js (and Knockout) are part of the MVVM framework and allow for a layer of seperation between your JavaScript functions and your presentation layer. jQuery, however, does not.

i.e.

MVVM:

User control -> ViewModel -> JavaScript processing

This JavaScript processing can be done via jQuery functions, jQuery and Backbone.js can work seamlessly together.

The main advantage? MVVM (Backbone.js), you're not relying on control ID's, if they change then your code still works. The jQuery way of specifically assigning IDs, this is not the case.

Me, personally, I'd take the MVVM approach.

Comment: I'm knew to backbone...the mvvm is a design pattern for client-server interactions?...If so, is backbone a client side or client and server side library...just getting started with backbone.

Comment: MVVM is a design pattern purely for client-client, it's a way of separating Presentation from Presentation Logic. I prefer (and recommend) Knockout.js to fully understand the MVVM pattern - it's a lot less time consuming to work with :)

Comment: That sounds complicated...MVVM all on the client?

Comment: Yep, it's a client framework, and a really nice way of working. It'll seperate your needs for concern when working with JavaScript (jQuery or not). If you're really new to all of this, I'd 100% recommend going through the Knockout.js tutorials (google it), and if you like developing in jQuery/JavaScript, be prepared to have a refreshing new approach to work with :)

Comment: It's worth noting that Backbone.js doesn't necessarily mean proper MVVM, as opposed to MVC or whathaveyou.  It's not quite so constrained as that, you can do whatever you please.

Comment: Very true, and thus quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: @thedixon...cool..thanks...finding good information on JavaScript is  a battle...